# Importing EXIF from filename

Tags: macos, date, filenames, exif, exiftool

Ok, so there are a plethora of examples and apps using [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to convert EXIF data to .jpg names. But what if you want to go the other way around? I have a number of files that use ODBC date, but contain no meta EXIF date. How can I - with what app or EXIFTool commandline - update the EXIF_DATE from a filename?

> 2012-02-24_1330073217.jpg

I found a Windows app 
[EXIFDate by filenamepattern](http://www.fileguru.com/EXIFDate-By-Filenamepattern/screenshot) that does this, but I'm a mac user. :/

Comment: I think you can done this by using `find`, `grep`, `cut` and exiftool command line to do this by pipe them together.
I'll try and post the answer if I found by this way!

Comment: With the command : `find ./ -name "*.jpg" | cut -d _ -f 1` you able to get the date if the format is like you said in your question. I'm not a user of exifTool so you have to complete by your own : use the result of `cut` and pipe it in exifTool or say to me how to set the date using exifTool

Comment: you want to do this via the command line and not programmatically, right?

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks a lot. I'm not too saavy with UNIX commands, but I'll use this as a test. I might want to make a macro or the likes if can find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This command will do what you want:

```
exiftool "-alldates<filename" DIR
```

where DIR is one or more directory and/or file names.